# Problem while installing oracle-java8-installer

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, openjdk, oracle

I am trying to install Oracle's Java8, but I get the following errors. How can I fix those?

<sub>Translated from Spanish. For original text, please see the revisions.</sub>

```
r06xd@uers1-H61MLV2:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
[sudo] password for r06xd: 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  ca-certificates-java fonts-dejavu-extra icedtea-6-jre-cacao
  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgconf2-4 libgif4
  libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0 liborbit-2-0 liborbit2
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre-headless
  ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Paquetes sugeridos:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core
  ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming
Los siguientes paquetes se ELIMINARÁN:
  jdk1.8.0-40
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  oracle-java8-installer
0 actualizados, 1 se instalarán, 1 para eliminar y 5 no actualizados.
1 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se necesita descargar 0 B/22,5 kB de archivos.
Se liberarán 244 MB después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] 
Preconfigurando paquetes ...
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 214592 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Removing jdk1.8.0-40 (1.8.040-1) ...
find: «/usr/java/*»: No existe el archivo o el directorio
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: línea 810: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No existe el archivo o el directorio
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: línea 822: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No existe el archivo o el directorio
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete jdk1.8.0-40 (--remove):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-removal devolvió el código de salida de error 127
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 jdk1.8.0-40
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is a translation of the error part:

```
find "/usr/java/*': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jdk1.8.0-40.postrm: line 810: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
```

Comment: No puedo espanol ,pero voy acqui -> `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html` ,  y `http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/`

Comment: Solo hablo un poquito espanol, y no puedo explicar que necesitas hacer bueno en espanol.  Pero es posible la guia aqui puede ayudarte.  http://www.ubuntu-guia.com/2012/04/instalar-oracle-java-7-en-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: Hey Rogger, what OS are you using? - Qué sistema operativo usas?

Comment: This is an English language site, are you able to write in English please - even if you use Google translate or something that's fine.

Comment: Prior to running this, did you attempt to manually remove the existing Java support by deleting `/usr/java`?

Comment: Please comment in English, or at least include an English translation ([like Lucio did](http://askubuntu.com/questions/608961/problem-while-installing-oracle-java8-installer#comment854061_608961)). Thanks!

Comment: hoola uso ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove -f
```

and then install Java8 again.